# Html and CSS editor that runs and saves code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap

I decided to create this project to put my JS skills to the test mostly, and it works well. It is a HTML and CSS editor that saves your code to `localstorage` and runs the code. On page load, it retrieves the `localstorage` saved code and runs it. The only minor issue is that the popup text that appears on hover of the save button can't dissapear when the button is disabled (after click) so it stays there forever. Is there any way to fix this? thank you!

I also used a bit of Bootstrap to align my elements and JQuery for some functionality.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Input saving test</title>
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 20px;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #383737;
        }
        textarea {
            height:100px;
            width:200px;
            padding:5px;
            overflow: none;
            border:5px solid aqua;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: black;
            color:white;
            
        }
        iframe {
            height:300px;
            width:auto;
            padding:5px;
            overflow: none;
            border:5px solid aqua;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
        #change-false-popup, #change-true-popup {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:90vh;
            border:2px solid white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
    <h1>HTML</h1>
    <textarea onkeyup="activateBtn()" type="text" id="html-input" placeholder="This code will save"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <h1>CSS</h1>
    <textarea onkeyup="activateBtn()" type="text" id="css-input" placeholder="This code will save"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="hidden" id="change-true-popup">Save and run code</div>
    <div class="hidden" id="change-false-popup">You need to make some changes first!</div>
    <br>
    <button id="save-btn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
    <iframe id="text-container"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
let input = document.getElementById('html-input');
let css_input = document.getElementById('css-input');
let container = document.getElementById('text-container');

function save() {
    let input_value = input.value;
    let css_input_value = css_input.value;

    localStorage.setItem('text', input_value);
    localStorage.setItem('css-text', css_input_value);
    
    container.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = `${input_value}<style>${css_input_value}</style>`;
    
    $("#save-btn").prop("disabled", true);
}
$('#save-btn').on('click', (event) => {
    let true_popup = document.getElementById('change-true-popup');

    true_popup.classList.add('hidden');
});
function activateBtn() {
    $("#save-btn").prop("disabled", false);
}
$('#save-btn').on('mouseover', (event) => {
    let true_popup = document.getElementById('change-true-popup');
    let false_popup = document.getElementById('change-false-popup');

    if ($('#save-btn').prop('disabled') === true) {
        false_popup.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
        true_popup.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
});
$('#save-btn').on('mouseout', (event) => {
    let true_popup = document.getElementById('change-true-popup');
    let false_popup = document.getElementById('change-false-popup');
    if ($('#save-btn').prop('disabled') === true) {
        false_popup.classList.add('hidden');
    } else {
        true_popup.classList.add('hidden');
    }
});

window.onload = function() {
    let savedText = localStorage.getItem('text');
    let savedCss = localStorage.getItem('css-text')
    if (savedText || savedCss) {
        container.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = `${savedText}<style>${savedCss}</style>`;
        input.value = savedText;
        css_input.value = savedCss;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The way to fix your popups is to always hide them after the save button was pressed. Note how it could be beneficial to have two functions: `showPopup(popupId)` and `hidePopup(popupId)`, to show and hide a popup. Note that it doesn't matter if you hide a hidden popup, and similarly you can show a popup that's already shown. The "hidden" class will only be added to, or removed from, a tag once.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware can you pls explain more how to implement that?

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Comment: Oh, the answer has now been deleted - I'll restore your edit.

Comment: Well, you use the "hidden" class to hide and show the popups and the popups have an "id" property. A show popup function could look like this: `function showPopup(popupId) { document.getElementById(popupId).remove('hidden'); }` and the hide popup function:  `function hidePopup(popupId) { document.getElementById(popupId).add('hidden'); }`. It will make your code a lot easier to read. You could use more general names like: `showTagById()` and `hideTagById()`, because it will work for all visible HTML tags.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware so do I like add an event listener for hover and then trigger the functions accordingly?

Comment: I think you can keep your `mouseover` and `mouseout` event handlers, but instead of first doing `let true_popup = document.getElementById('change-true-popup');` and then `true_popup.classList.add('hidden');` you can simply do: `hidePopup('change-true-popup');`.

Comment: Saving and loading strings can be improved by using `JSON.stringify()` before saving into localstorage, and using `JSON.parse()` after retrieving from localStorage. And since this is CodeReview I would also suggest removing jQuery, it serves no purpose (unless you want to support Internet Explorer 6)